flutter web: pathParameters is not printed on address-bar by go router
I am using go router on my Flutter web. I want to pass id to other page and also showing this address on address bar:
GoRoute(
  path: "/main_category/:id",
  name: "mainCategory",
  builder: (context, state) {
    return MainCategoryScreen(
      mainCategoryId: state.pathParameters["id"]!,
    );
  },
),

and I am using in this way:
InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    context.pushNamed("mainCategory",
      pathParameters: {"id": e.uuid!});
     },

this is my widget:
class MainCategoryScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainCategoryScreen({super.key, required this.mainCategoryId});

  final String mainCategoryId;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Consumer(
        builder: (context, ref, child) {
          return Center(
            child: Text(mainCategoryId),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

The id is printed on the center but this address Is not added in browser address bar, What is the issue ?
I am using last version of flutter SDK and go router .
my main dart:
 MaterialApp.router(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
          useMaterial3: true,
        ),
        routerConfig: router,
      ),

the log shows this:
[GoRouter] pushing /main_category/4619e96f-14ea-4a12-a0b0-e83f79e97f73


can you share code of pushName extension

it is not an extension, it is for Go router function
